# Resource File access "InvocationTargetException" in Android Unit Test

Tags: android, mockito, powermockito

**JUnitTest/Mockito/PowerMockito ::** Trying to access dataSet json file from res/raw file in android, But getting "**InvocationTargetException**"

```js
InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resource.json");
        try {
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8");
            ConfigModel result  = new Gson().fromJson(reader, ConfigModel.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: updated version.
If you using Android instrumentation test then you can get the `context` and you can do something like this,

```
@Test
public void someTest() {
    // Context of the app under test. 
    // In this case put your resource in your app's assets folder src/main/assets
    Context appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();

    / **
    * Context of the test app. 
    * In this case put your resource in your test app's assets folder src/androidTests/assets
    * Context appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getContext();
    **/

    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = appContext.getAssets().open("resource.json");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

If you do not want to go into Android way of testing, simple way is to have your `resource.json` under `src/test/resources` folder and then your above code would work. Something like this.

```
@Test
public void test() {
        ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
        InputStream res = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("testFlags.json");
}
```

I did some testing around these and I can say they are working fine. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Hi Abhishek, Have you checked this code with Mockito/PowerMockitoRunner for Unit test?

Comment: Hi Amit, I updated my answer, Have a look and let me know how does it go.

Comment: For instrumentation test your code is okay but for JUnit it's not working. I am asking for junit test only...

Comment: Ok, my bad, you have to put your `resource.json` file under `src/test/resources` folder. https://www.dropbox.com/s/c5mih513kzg80f1/Resource.png?dl=0
Attached screenshot of passing test and my dir structure.
Corrected the answer.